# ¿Cómo redireccionar una pagina existente hacia otra?

Tags: html, web, iis

Tengo una pagina web en IIS lo cual cuando el cliente accede hacia la raíz, obtiene un código 403 no autorizado.

Lo que requiero hacer es que ese URL cuando sea consultado desde el externo, pueda ser reenviado hacia otro que si es posible de acceder.

Sé que se puede hacer en IIS directamente y quisiera hacerlo en HTML ya que si el servidor fuese migrado hacia otro servidor, la página HTML puede copiarse y modificarse facilemente.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer lo puedes configurar desde el IIS, en `Error Pages`:

[image: Configuración de paginas de error en IIS]

En el error 403, deberías poner la ruta la pagina que deseas mostrar cuando ocurra ese error.

En este enlace podras encontrar una pagina que profundiza sobre el tema:
[How To Set Up Custom Error Pages](http://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/)

[image: Configuración de paginas de error en IIS]

Esto también se puede hacer desde el web.config, en caso de que estés trabajando con .Net debería ser algo como lo siguiente:

```xml
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" >
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="/Error/401" />
      <error statusCode="402" redirect="/Error/402" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Error/403" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/404" />
      <error statusCode="405" redirect="/Error/405" />
      <error statusCode="406" redirect="/Error/406" />
      <error statusCode="407" redirect="/Error/407" />
      <error statusCode="408" redirect="/Error/408" />
      <error statusCode="409" redirect="/Error/409" />
      <error statusCode="410" redirect="/Error/410" />
      <error statusCode="411" redirect="/Error/411" />
    </customErrors>  
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta. Pero es eso lo que estoy evitando de hacer, es el usar IIs. No puedo usar IIS.

Comment: Que tecnologías esta utilizando la pagina? (.Net, PHP, HTML?)

Comment: Hola estoy usando html y .net

Comment: Entonces prueba con la configuración de `customErrors` en el web.config,  `<error statusCode="403" redirect="/Error/403" /> `